# How do I make an addEventListener to work once until I close a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, addeventlistener

So. I have a button that changes the visibility to the div -> spotPopUp. 
I made an eventlistener to simply change the visibility of the div (hidd to visible and so on)
The problem?
How do I make the button be able to be pressed only once till the "Cancel" or "Submit" are pressed?
When I apply the removeEventListener it isn't added back when calling the function.

```js
var spot = document.getElementById("spot");
spot.addEventListener("click", spotClick);

function spotClick() {
  spot.addEventListener("click", spotClick);
  let popUp = document.getElementById("spotPopUp");
  if (popUp.style.visibility == "visible") {
    popUp.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    popUp.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  spot.removeEventListener("click", spotClick);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="ADD SPOT" id="spot" />
<div id="spotPopUp">
  <h3>Add a Marker</h3>
  <a onclick="spotClick()"><p>Cancel</p></a>
  <a onclick="saveMarker()"><p>Add Marker</p></a>
</div>
```

I hope that I can get myself understood sorry for my bad english in advance.

Comment: *I have a button that opens a div* Ok, well stop right there. What does that even mean "open a div"? And, also please update your question to include the relevant HTML and CSS as well as the JavaScript.

Comment: @Scott Marcus By *opens* he means *displays*, according to the second sentence.

Comment: @Marius-N If I understood correctly, you want to trigger the click event only once and then remove the event until some other button is clicked that is part of the div you made visible?

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes. If I press the Cancel or Submit button from the spotPopUp div I want to be able to use that eventlistener again. (spot.addEventListener("click", spotClick);)

Comment: You misspelled `removeEventListener()`.

Comment: Now, it's clear that you are trying to find an element with an `id` of `spot`, but the element actually has an `id` of `spotPopUp`. Fix your typos.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The `id` of `spot` is the button I press to "display" the spotPopUp.

Comment: But you didn't originally add that to your code. Post ALL the relevant code so we can reproduce your issue exactly and provide a working result.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. Don't unbind the handler. Set the button to disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call the `spotClick()` on the Cancel element, it will ultimately remove the event listener, since that is literally the last command in it.

What you need are different functions for those two clicks. First, your `spotClick()` should only make your pop-up visible and have nothing to do with hiding, while removing the event listener:

```
function spotClick() {
  document.getElementById("spotPopUp").style.visibility = "visible";
  spot.removeEventListener("click", spotClick);
}
```

Then, you need a separate function which will hide it and reattach the event listener:

```
function cancelClick() {
  document.getElementById("spotPopUp").style.visibility = "hidden";
  spot.addEventListener("click", spotClick);
}
```

Full snippet:

```js
var spot = document.getElementById("spot");
spot.addEventListener("click", spotClick);

function spotClick() {
  document.getElementById("spotPopUp").style.visibility = "visible";
  spot.removeEventListener("click", spotClick);
}
function cancelClick() {
  document.getElementById("spotPopUp").style.visibility = "hidden";
  spot.addEventListener("click", spotClick);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="ADD SPOT" id="spot" />
<div id="spotPopUp" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <h3>Add a Marker</h3>
  <a onclick="cancelClick()"><p>Cancel</p></a>
  <a onclick="saveMarker()"><p>Add Marker</p></a>
</div>
```

Comment: So I was just complicating myself with something that doesn't work. Thanks a lot. <3

Comment: This may "work", but it's entirely the wrong approach. Also, your explanation of the problem is wrong. The `addEventListener` is being added twice, while the `removeEventListener()` is only being called once, so there is still a listener on the button even after remove is called.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `click` handler to the button twice, but only removing it once. Remove the second addition of the handler and it works.

```js
var spot = document.getElementById("spot");
spot.addEventListener("click", spotClick);

function spotClick() {
  // spot.addEventListener("click", spotClick);  <-- PROBLEM IS HERE
  let popUp = document.getElementById("spotPopUp");
  if (popUp.style.visibility == "visible") {
    popUp.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    popUp.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  spot.removeEventListener("click", spotClick);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="ADD SPOT" id="spot" />
<div id="spotPopUp" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <h3>Add a Marker</h3>
  <a onclick="spotClick()"><p>Cancel</p></a>
  <a onclick="saveMarker()"><p>Add Marker</p></a>
</div>
```

And, you can simplify this code a great deal if you remove the inline event handlers and CSS:

```js
// Get references to the elements you'll need to work with just once
let popUp = document.getElementById("spotPopUp");
let cancel = document.querySelector(".cancel");
let add = document.querySelector(".addMarker");

// Do your event binding in JavaScript, not inline in HTML
document.getElementById("spot").addEventListener("click", spotClick);
cancel.addEventListener("click", spotClick);
add.addEventListener("click", saveMarker);

function spotClick() {
  // Just toggle the use of the hidden class. 
  // No removeEventListener, if/then/else or inline style manipulation needed.
  popUp.classList.toggle("hidden");
}

function saveMarker(){
 // code here
}
```

```css
/* Use CSS classes instead of inline CSS */
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<!--
  Don't use self-terminating syntax, it's only needed in XHTML and can 
  lead to confusion when not used properly.
  
  Don't use inline CSS or JavaScript. Separate your languages.
  
  Don't use <a> tags just for click event handling. Just about every
  HTML element supports a click event.
-->
<input type="button" value="ADD SPOT" id="spot">
<div id="spotPopUp" class="hidden">
  <h3>Add a Marker</h3>
  <p class="cancel">Cancel</p>
  <p class="addMarker">Add Marker</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm still able to "close" the popUp using the same button.
`<input type="button" value="ADD SPOT" id="spot" />`
I want this button to only "open" the popUp not to close it as well.

Comment: Does not work for multiple clicks. The event handler isn't reattaching.

Comment: @Marius-N See my updated answer. My first example answers your question about why `removeEventListener()` wasn't working - so that answers your main question. My second example shows how to make the whole thing work the way you want.

Comment: @El_Vanja See my updated answer. My first example answers the question about why `removeEventListener()` wasn't working - so that answers your main question. My second example shows how to make the whole thing work the way it should.

Comment: Second snippet doesn't remove the event handler and still allows toggling the pop-up with the ADD SPOT button. I suggest you combine your solutions into one that covers all the questions. I agree with all your advice on how to make the code cleaner, I just didn't want to overwhelm the OP. And while we're on that subject, those `let`s should really be `const`s as they're never reassigned.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I'm not unbinding the handler.